# Accdentally locked headless Raspberry Pi

Tags: networking

I accidentally disconnected my headless raspberry pi because of a stupid mistake I made, now it won't be able to reconnect to wifi, so I can't ssh into it and so on.

Essentially, I modified this file `/etc/dhcpd.conf` to had it written

```
interfaces wlan0
nohook wpa_supplicant
```

the above line apparently stops wpa_supplicant from working. So I wanted to delete these 2 lines by inserting the SD card into my Windows desktop and trying to delete it. However, I only stumbled upon a boot sector and the actual filesystem was not formattable in Windows. I tried to use Ext2Fsd and that almost crashed my machine. Is there a way to override this `dhcpd.conf` file so that my raspberry pi will use a wpa_supplicant.conf to reconnect to my network?

Answer (score 1):

You should note that your SD card has two partitions: `/` (root), and `/boot`.

- `/` uses the `ext4` filesystem & contains `/etc`
- `/boot` uses `fat32` - it's where you create `/boot/ssh`, and `wpa_supplicant`

Easiest thing to try 1st is mount `/boot` & create a new `wpa_supplicant`. But I doubt this will cure your problem. :(

The next option is to mount `/` & repair the damage in `/etc/dhcpd.conf`. IMHO, you're wasting your time with Windows gadgets, but there is a viable, and free alternative:

Download an [Ubuntu "Live" image](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started), install it on a USB stick, and boot your Windows PC into Ubuntu. Ubuntu also "speaks" `ext4`, so you can mount your RPi SD card & repair the error you've made. Note that this ***does not*** install Ubuntu on your Windows PC - nor does it make any debilitating changes to the HDD. After you finish repair of your SD card, you shut down, remove the "Live" USB stick & reboot into Windows. Here's a [tutorial on the process](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/) if you're uncomfortable with it.